# Gmail add-on,how is the method of updating only message

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I would like to make addon for Gmail but i can't because of some issue.
When i try to ''update'' ''GmailDraft'' it's not coming ''reply'' of ''GmailMessage.createDraftreply''.

Could anyone teach me how is the method of updating only message on ''GmailDraft''

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts and a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) on how to use the methods in [Class GmailDraft](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft).

> A user-created draft message in a user's Gmail account.

To update the draft, try the [update(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String)) method or [update(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#updaterecipient-subject-body-options) if you have optional arguments.

Also, if you are having problems with the reply, maybe [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#createDraftReply(String)) could help.

There is a sample code on how to create a draft message as a reply to the sender.